# Grid Colouring: $4\times4$ chessboard case

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, chessboard

Every side of every unit square in a $4\times4$ chessboard is coloured either red or blue. What is the maximum number of blue sides such that every unit square has at most one blue side?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The maximum values for $n \times n$ seem to match $a(n-1)$ here: https://oeis.org/A265284

Comment: It stated that the answer is 20, how do I know? May you explain or give me a hint?

Comment: Via integer linear programming, the maximum is $14$.  Even just considering each unit square individually yields an upper bound of $16$.  Who claims $20$?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I checked that 14 blue sides are possible. Now the question is how to prove that 15 blue sides are impossible? I tried to use Pigeon Hole Principle but no idea yet. If there is a hint? Thank

Comment: Hint: Warm up with the $3\times 3$ case, where the maximum is $8$. To see that the easy upper bound of $9$ is unattainable, consider what happens if you color blue a side of the center square.